# Getting no SOAPAction header error in sending a SOAP request as HTTP POST

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, soapui

I am sending a SOAP Request as HTTP POST in SOAPUI due to some project constraints.
My Request is here :

```
POST httplink HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_WS/HelpDesk_Query_Service"
Content-Length: 725
Host: itsm-mt-dev
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)


<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_WS">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
         <urn:userName>XXXXXXXXXX</urn:userName>
         <urn:password>XXXXXXXXX</urn:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:authentication>?</urn:authentication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:locale>?</urn:locale>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:timeZone>?</urn:timeZone>
      </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:HelpDesk_Query_Service>
         <urn:Incident_Number>XXXXXXXXXX</urn:Incident_Number>
      </urn:HelpDesk_Query_Service>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Although I had set SOAPAction header, still I am getting no SOAPAction header error.

Response as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
         <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">itsm-mt-dev</ns2:hostname>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anyone suggest me what we can do here ?

Comment: In your WSDL look for a line which looks something like `<soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/GetLastTradePrice"/>`. What is the soapAction equal to for the `HelpDesk_Query_Service` operation?

Answer (score 25):

It looks like you are sending an incorrect soapAction header. Look at the WSDL and find out the value for soapAction element for the service being tested.

In the WSDL look for a line similar to `<soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/GetLastTradePrice"/>`.

Answer (score 10):

You have to add `SOAPAction`:  `add` if post API.

[image: postman image]

Answer (score 7):

```
request.Headers.Add( "SOAPAction", YOUR SOAP ACTION );
```

Comment: Create a httpwebrequest  and then add headers to it
`code`Dim bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("soap")
Dim wr As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("xx")
wr.Headers.Add("ur soap hdr", "xxx")
wr.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
wr.Method = "POST"
wr.ContentLength = bs.Length
Dim sds As Stream = wr.GetRequestStream()
sds.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length)
sds.Close()
Dim wr As WebResponse = wr.GetResponse()
sds = wr.GetResponseStream()
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(sds)
Dim strResult As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
txtResult.Text = strResult
sds.Close()
sr.Close()
wr.Close()`code`

Answer (score 5):

Just add `SOAPAction` parameter to the request header with empty quotation marks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case (wsdl) is unknown, and I have only end point url. Following snippet worked for me to perform soap api xml import:

```
import requests

xml = """<mysoapxml>"""

# here "http://myendpoint/url" is service url (not a wsdl)

headers = {
    'content-type': "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    'soapaction': 'http://myendpoint/url'
}

resp = requests.post('http://myendpoint/url', data=xml, headers=headers).text

print(resp)
```

Note: `'soapaction': 'http://myendpoint/url'` is mandatory to eliminate `no SOAPAction header`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add comment in the answer suggested by ynneh but the code was not readable.
His answer is useful but is too short.

Create a httpwebrequest  and then add headers to it.
following is complete example:

```
    Dim bytSoap = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("soap content")

        Dim wrRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("xxxxx")

        wrRequest.Headers.Add("your soap header", "xxx")

        wrRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        wrRequest.Method = "POST"
        wrRequest.ContentLength = bytSoap.Length

        Dim sDataStream As Stream = wrRequest.GetRequestStream()
        sDataStream.Write(bytSoap, 0, bytSoap.Length)
        sDataStream.Close()

        Dim wrResponse As WebResponse = wrRequest.GetResponse()
        sDataStream = wrResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim srReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(sDataStream)
        Dim strResult As String = srReader.ReadToEnd()
        txtResult.Text = strResult
        sDataStream.Close()
        srReader.Close()
        wrResponse.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the SOAPAction, we can goto SOAP UI request ->Raw. Use this in the request & should do the job

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**// Delphi**

```
var
 xmlhttp : IXMLHTTPRequest; // unit MSXML2_TLB
begin
 xmlhttp := CoXMLHTTP.Create;
 xmlhttp.open('POST', Edit7.Text, False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction','POST')
```

Comment: SOAPAction value ambiguously confuses the reader with the HTTP method while not technically incorrect.  -1